# WebStorm does not see a git .exe. Why?

Tags: git, ide, webstorm

WebStorm does not see a git .exe. Why?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to include the name of the exe itself, not just the directory. The option text is misleading, the error message isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path should include the executable, like `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`